# Flexigrid + IE9 height:auto

Tags: height, internet-explorer-9, flexigrid

The problem is very elemental.

If you go to http://flexigrid.info/ **with IE9**, and explore the '**example 2**' section, and the columns resize over the visible place, that it will activate the horizontal scrollbar. And you hover the rows, you experience growing up the Flexigrid size. I don't experience IE7 and IE8, only IE9. This problem has by height: auto configurate. I didn't find solution yet. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the solution that @Szenti posted will only work for 1 flexigrid on the page, if there are multiple, it will only takes the height value of the 1st bDiv it founds and apply the fix to all.

My revised version I think will apply to situations where there are many flexigrids on the page at one time.

```
ie9Fix: function() {
            var bDivH = $(this.bDiv).height();
            var bDivTH = $('table', this.bDiv).height();
            if(bDivH != bDivTH && p.height=='auto') {
               $(".bDiv").css({height: bDivTH + 18});
            }
        },
```

Comment: I have write a patch according to this comments on the flexigrid issues page : http://code.google.com/p/flexigrid/issues/detail?id=112

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. Thanks @Szenti for the Answer, however, once this was in place I then had flexigrid resize issue when the results in the table where regenerated via AJAX. This occured in latest Chrome, Firefox and IE7/8.

So I added a (some would say dirty) browser sniff into the mix.

Global var:

```
var ie9 = false;
if ($.browser.msie && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 9) {
    ie9 = true;
}
```

Then where @Szanti's method is called I just wrap it in:

```
if (ie9) {
 this.ie9Fix();
}
```

Now works a treat in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

You have to edit the flexigrid js. Append the g object with this:

```
ie9Fix: function() {
if($(".bDiv").height() != $(".bDiv table").height() && p.height=='auto') {
   $(".bDiv").css({height: $(".bDiv table").height() + 18});
}
},
```

You have to call ie9Fix function in 2 places

- In the g.dragEnd() function last row (this.ie9Fix();)
- In the g.addRowProp() you have to write a new event:

  .mouseleave(function(){
  g.ie9Fix();
  })

That's it!